# Is this interpretation of Enthalpy and Internal Energy correct?

Tags: thermodynamics

Enthalpy is basically, Internal energy plus the additional amount of energy which was lost (due to -pdV) so as to get a term which gives the REAL CHANGE IN INTERNAL ENERGY.

Or it can be said that enthalpy is the net change in Internal energy in terms of ONLY HEAT?

There is always volume work which gets lost during chemical reactions at constant pressure from the Total U change. H just gives us entire change in U in terms of qp ( compensating for the loss in the form of volume work).

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Not a detailed answer, but trying to decide what $H=U+PV$ means physically is difficult.  What matters is the *change* in enthalpy, $\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta (PV)$.  This second term is needed to account for the volume of the gas changing during the process.

Answer (score 0):

Enthalpy is defined $H = U + PV$ where $U$ is internal energy, $P$ is pressure, and $V$ is volume.  Enthalpy per unit mass is $h = u + Pv$ where $h$, $u$, and $v$ are enthalpy per unit mass, internal energy per unit mass, and specific volume, respectively.

Enthalpy is fundamental to an energy balance (first law of thermodynamics) on an open thermodynamic system- one with mass flow in and/out of the system boundaries- as enthalpy considers the energy in/out of the system due to mass entering/leaving the system. The $pv$ term is flow energy when energy flow in/out of the open thermodynamic system is considered.  If the system is defined as following a moving fixed mass, $pv$ is flow work.

Enthalpy accounts for energy due to mass flow in/out of an open thermodynamic system.  Heat can also provide energy in/out of the system. Enthalpy and heat are separate concepts.

Enthalpy also is associated with slow expansion in a constant pressure process in a closed thermodynamic system (no mass transfer): $Q = \Delta U + W  =\Delta U + p\Delta V = \Delta U + \Delta (pV) = \Delta H$. where $Q$ is the heat added to the system and $W$ is the work done by the system.

See a good thermodynamics text, such as one by Sonntag and Van Wylen for more detailed explanations.

I do not follow your comment about chemical reactions, can you please clarify?  There is an "enthalpy of formation" for a chemical reaction; is this what you are referring to?